# No se aplica color correctamente con css

Tags: css, css3

```css
.reproduction-played{
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #BB0101;
    width: 0;
}

.reproduction-played::before{
    content: "\f111";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    top: -5.3px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #BB0101;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="reproduction-played">
</div>
```

Tengo un div al cual le aplico la pseudoclase `before` pero el problema viene al aplicar color al font de la pseudo clase, como ven el color que le aplico solo lo pone en el borde y no rellenado como debería de ser.

Porque esta pasando esto??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fontawesome usa el mismo unicode para todos los grosores de fuente, negrita, regular, light, etc, solo debes agregar el `font-weight` correspondiente al grosor de la fuente. en este caso `font-weight: 900;`

```css
.reproduction-played{
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #BB0101;
    width: 0;
}

.reproduction-played::before{
    content: "\f111";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    top: -5.3px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #BB0101;
    font-weight: 900; /* Grosor de fuente */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="reproduction-played">
</div>
```